# Java: Get Sample Request XML from wsdl

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

Is there any way one could get the sample request xml using the wsdl(url) alone?

Here is a sample wsdl: http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL
Sample Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ws="http://webservicemart.com/ws/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:ValidateZip>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ws:ZipCode>?</ws:ZipCode>
      </ws:ValidateZip>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I know there are tools out there like SOAPUI and others which could do this. But is there any other way without using these tools once could achieve it using java?

Using wsimport would be one option that would get me the java source, this is more static. Is there a dynamic way to do this?

**Exception encountered:**

```
18:57:59,677 WARN  [SoapUI] Missing folder [D:\TestAutomation\Z_ZZLastResort\.\ext] for external libraries
18:57:59,920 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] initialized soapui-settings from [C:\Users\mike\soapui-settings.xml]
Progress: 1 - Caching Definition from url [http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL]
18:58:00,587 INFO  [SchemaUtils] Added default schema from file:/C:/Users/mike/Desktop/soapui-4.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/eviware/soapui/resources/xsds/xop.xsd with targetNamespace http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include
18:58:00,625 INFO  [SchemaUtils] Added default schema from file:/C:/Users/mike/Desktop/soapui-4.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/eviware/soapui/resources/xsds/XMLSchema.xsd with targetNamespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
18:58:00,627 INFO  [SchemaUtils] Added default schema from file:/C:/Users/mike/Desktop/soapui-4.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/eviware/soapui/resources/xsds/xml.xsd with targetNamespace http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace
18:58:00,628 INFO  [SchemaUtils] Added default schema from file:/C:/Users/mike/Desktop/soapui-4.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/eviware/soapui/resources/xsds/swaref.xsd with targetNamespace http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.1/xsd
18:58:00,629 INFO  [SchemaUtils] Added default schema from file:/C:/Users/mike/Desktop/soapui-4.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/eviware/soapui/resources/xsds/xmime200505.xsd with targetNamespace http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime
18:58:00,637 INFO  [SchemaUtils] Added default schema from file:/C:/Users/mike/Desktop/soapui-4.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/eviware/soapui/resources/xsds/xmime200411.xsd with targetNamespace http://www.w3.org/2004/11/xmlmime
18:58:00,638 INFO  [SchemaUtils] Added default schema from file:/C:/Users/mike/Desktop/soapui-4.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/eviware/soapui/resources/xsds/soapEnvelope.xsd with targetNamespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
18:58:00,641 INFO  [SchemaUtils] Added default schema from file:/C:/Users/mike/Desktop/soapui-4.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/eviware/soapui/resources/xsds/soapEncoding.xsd with targetNamespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
18:58:00,643 INFO  [SchemaUtils] Added default schema from file:/C:/Users/mike/Desktop/soapui-4.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/eviware/soapui/resources/xsds/soapEnvelope12.xsd with targetNamespace http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
18:58:00,645 INFO  [SchemaUtils] Added default schema from file:/C:/Users/mike/Desktop/soapui-4.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/eviware/soapui/resources/xsds/soapEncoding12.xsd with targetNamespace http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding
Progress: 2 - Loading [http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL]
18:58:00,648 DEBUG [WsdlLoader] Getting wsdl component from [http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL]
18:58:01,073 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
18:58:01,074 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: GET /uszip.asmx?WSDL HTTP/1.1
18:58:01,314 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection closed
18:58:01,314 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Closing the connection.
18:58:01,314 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection closed
18:58:01,314 INFO  [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset
18:58:01,316 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:264)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:98)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpClientSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.UrlWsdlLoader$LoaderWorker.construct(UrlWsdlLoader.java:226)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.UrlWsdlLoader.load(UrlWsdlLoader.java:138)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlLoader.loadXmlObject(WsdlLoader.java:121)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getDefinitionParts(SchemaUtils.java:535)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getDefinitionParts(SchemaUtils.java:524)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionCache.update(AbstractDefinitionCache.java:97)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext$Loader.construct(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:226)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorkerDelegator.construct(SwingWorkerDelegator.java:46)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:149)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
18:58:01,319 INFO  [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Retrying request
18:58:01,319 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Reopening the direct connection.
18:58:01,602 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 2 to execute request
18:58:01,602 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: GET /uszip.asmx?WSDL HTTP/1.1
18:58:02,200 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
18:58:02,210 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
Progress: 1 - Loading Definition from url
18:58:02,260 DEBUG [AbstractDefinitionContext] Loading Definition...
18:58:02,277 DEBUG [WsdlInterfaceDefinition] Loading WSDL: http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL
18:58:02,277 DEBUG [AbstractWsdlDefinitionLoader] Returning baseInputSource [http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL]
Retrieving document at 'http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL'.
18:58:02,347 INFO  [SchemaUtils] Loading schema types from [http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL]
18:58:02,347 INFO  [SchemaUtils] Getting schema http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL
18:58:02,357 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occured [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xb.xsdschema.impl.SchemaDocumentImpl], see error log for details
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xb.xsdschema.impl.SchemaDocumentImpl
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getSchemas(SchemaUtils.java:418)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getSchemas(SchemaUtils.java:327)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.loadSchemaTypes(SchemaUtils.java:192)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.XmlSchemaBasedInterfaceDefinition.loadSchemaTypes(XmlSchemaBasedInterfaceDefinition.java:79)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlInterfaceDefinition.load(WsdlInterfaceDefinition.java:61)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlContext.loadDefinition(WsdlContext.java:66)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlContext.loadDefinition(WsdlContext.java:30)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext.cacheDefinition(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:268)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext.access$400(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:44)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext$Loader.construct(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:235)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorkerDelegator.construct(SwingWorkerDelegator.java:46)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:149)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
18:58:02,359 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occured [com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaException], see error log for details
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaException
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getSchemas(SchemaUtils.java:512)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getSchemas(SchemaUtils.java:327)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.loadSchemaTypes(SchemaUtils.java:192)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.XmlSchemaBasedInterfaceDefinition.loadSchemaTypes(XmlSchemaBasedInterfaceDefinition.java:79)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlInterfaceDefinition.load(WsdlInterfaceDefinition.java:61)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlContext.loadDefinition(WsdlContext.java:66)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlContext.loadDefinition(WsdlContext.java:30)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext.cacheDefinition(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:268)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext.access$400(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:44)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext$Loader.construct(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:235)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorkerDelegator.construct(SwingWorkerDelegator.java:46)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:149)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
18:58:02,360 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occured [com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaException], see error log for details
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaException
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getSchemas(SchemaUtils.java:512)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.getSchemas(SchemaUtils.java:327)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.xsd.SchemaUtils.loadSchemaTypes(SchemaUtils.java:192)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.XmlSchemaBasedInterfaceDefinition.loadSchemaTypes(XmlSchemaBasedInterfaceDefinition.java:79)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlInterfaceDefinition.load(WsdlInterfaceDefinition.java:61)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlContext.loadDefinition(WsdlContext.java:66)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlContext.loadDefinition(WsdlContext.java:30)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext.cacheDefinition(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:268)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext.access$400(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:44)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.definition.support.AbstractDefinitionContext$Loader.construct(AbstractDefinitionContext.java:235)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorkerDelegator.construct(SwingWorkerDelegator.java:46)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.swing.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:149)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
18:58:02,363 ERROR [AbstractDefinitionContext] Error loading schema types from http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL, see log for details
18:58:35,061 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection closed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/Developers-Corner/integrating-with-soapui.html) also provide java API to create request/response

```
public class SOAPInputGenerator {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
    WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "http://localhost:7000/Solicitud?wsdl");
    WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[0];
    for (Operation operation : wsdl.getOperationList()) {
        WsdlOperation wsdlOperation = (WsdlOperation) operation;
        System.out.println("OP:"+wsdlOperation.getName());
        System.out.println("Request:");
        System.out.println(wsdlOperation.createRequest(true));
        System.out.println("Response:");
        System.out.println(wsdlOperation.createResponse(true));
    }
}
}
```

JAR location for SOAP UI libraries

http://www.soapui.org/repository/eviware/jars/

---

If you don't want use SOAPUI directly , you may find `reficio` which would be very useful.
Subset of SoapUI library  API with example can be find here

https://github.com/reficio/soap-ws

http://www.reficio.org/projects/

This is an open-source project to support SOAP in a purely XML way in Java

Comment: Thank you Satheesh. This looks neat. I am not able to download the SOAP UI Jar for this. Could you please point me to it?

Comment: Have you got this working? I am trying and every time I try to run my code, I get a class Not found error..

Comment: What is the class is missing? it required dependency jars such as *xmlbeans.jar

Comment: There are several jars in the lib folder that we would get when we install SOAP UI. I copied all the jar(including xmlbeans.jar). There were no more errors. But when I run my code. I get the following error.18:24:40,220 WARN  [SoapUI] Missing folder [D:\TestAutomation\Z_ZZLastResort\.\ext] for external libraries
18:24:40,492 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] initialized soapui-settings from [C:\Users\mike\soapui-settings.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V

Comment: A NoSuchMethodError indicates that classes available at runtime are different to those used to compile your code. which version of httpclient do you have? http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0-alpha4

Comment: Thanks Satheesh. I had added a manually downloaded http client. I removed that and I got a different exception. Please see the Original question. I have added the exception details.

Comment: Got this working. Added all the required dependencies using maven. Thank you.

Comment: @Mike could you please post your pom and imports

Answer (score 1):

You can create the client side stubs using wsimport tool and use jaxb to convert your request object to SOAP xml.

Comment: Thanks hanish.kh. Using wsimport would be static, Is there a more dynamic way to do this??

Comment: How about a dynamic client? Might be helpful http://www.soapuser.com/ngx_22jul01_SoapClientHelper_java.html