# Generate XML from WSDL

Tags: xml, wsdl

I have a wsdl link that has login service and it takes username and password as parameter. I want to print something like below for this login service. I mean i want the below xml as String.

```
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bean:login>
         <request>
            <password></password>
            <userName></userName>
         </request>
      </bean:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

Is there any java library available for this? Or is it possible to do?

Comment: Once I had the idea of writing something similar, but gave up because it turned out that either the request for this functionality is very rare or it's already made available by some tools or libraries. Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486743/java-get-sample-request-xml-from-wsdl ?

Comment: Yeah saw that. I have to write code :(