# Tool to generate SOAP Request from WSDL

Tags: web-services

I'm using curl to test my Web services sending SOAP Request. Right now I need some UI tools to generate the sample SOAP Request to be sent. Is there any shell tool (Fedora/RHEL) which lets you generate a SOAP Request from a WSDL ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, it is a download link for the new SOAP UI tool with added functionality you might require if you don't have it already.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/

Comment: This post on SO already answered your question :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222607/how-to-do-a-soap-wsdl-web-services-call-from-the-command-line

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in the link that you provided you do know already the xml structure of the request. I'm looking for a way to generate said request from wsdl. I asked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59307801/linux-command-line-tool-for-generate-xml-request-from-wsdl) SO post

Comment: If this link here doesn't help you, then I really don't understand your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35908226/generating-request-response-xml-from-a-wsdl

Comment: As regards a command line, you would have to generate your scripts according to your wsdl settings. I don't think there is a general solution one liner that can conform to every wsdl requests. The link I sent above, one of the answers has a way for you to be able to write your request which you can then curl after you have extracted your settings. Hope that helps