# how to generate XML request of SOAP webservice like SOAPUI request with PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, wsdl, soapui

I want to create an application with `PHP` that get `WSDL` and method name from user and generate a `SOAP` request just like `SOAPUI`.

in fact I want to create application just like `SOAPUI` that create `XML` request and let user edit it and fill the requested parameters.

how could I do that?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Are you expecting someone to show you a complete code base?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no, I want to know is there any class or already exist git source for this job

Comment: I think the only way you can get this done is by doing it the same way as the people that built "SOAPUI" did it...  build it...

Comment: Another solution would be to use SOAPUI, since they have done exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson SOAPUI have an API that create what I want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486743/java-get-sample-request-xml-from-wsdl, is there any equivalent in PHP?

Comment: I really don't get what you're asking for. If they have an API, why not use that?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson because its java library, I can't use them in my PHP Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution :)

as far as I know there is no `PHP` equivalent for `SOAPUI`.
so I found that there is a `API` in `SOAPUI` with help of @satheesh-cheveri in following link, and create `JAVA` program to use it and then call the `JAVA` application inside my `PHP` application:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20487079/1665693

I take a long time to find out what library needed to be imported so I list it here for everyone who needed:

- apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar
- apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar
- apache-xml-xerces.jar
- bcprov-jdk15-144.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
- commons-cli-1.3.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.jar
- junit-4.4.jar
- log4j-1.2.8.jar
- rsyntaxtextarea-1.4.1.jar
- soapui-4.5.0.jar
- soapui-xmlbeans-4.5.0.jar
- wsdl4j-1.6.2-fixed.jar
- xbean-fixed-2.4.0.jar

and here is my function I asked for:

```
public String generateSampleRequest(String wsdl, String method) {
    String result = "";
    try {
        WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
        WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, wsdl);
        WsdlInterface ws = wsdls[0];
        WsdlOperation wsdlOperation = ws.getOperationByName(method);
        result = wsdlOperation.createRequest(true);
        ws.release();
        project.release();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = e.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `SoapServer`. More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php).

---

**EDIT**
I forgot to add [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php). Thanks [Magnus Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson)

Comment: I look for class or already exist php application that create sample XML request

Comment: I think he's rather looking for [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) - which is what the majority of people would use. Creating your own XML-data just seems silly.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have an application that people could use their webservice in it,so I need to give them an interface to create the XML request, It should be edited by themselves because of the complexity in some web service

Comment: If you mean to create/edit WSDL or XML, you should use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) and files ([fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)) to create/edit them...

Comment: I want a class or function that give WSDL and method name and bring me a sample request XML, do you see SOAPUI? just like SOAPUI request

Comment: Sorry, I dont get what you are asking for... If you mean to use a WSDL that you have defined and with that do a XML request, use SoapServer. Can anyone upvote this answer... i got answer banned... pls

Comment: I think he asks if anyone have "a class" that can do the same thing as the application "SOAPUI". The answer is probably... no. He most likely needs to build it himself...

Comment: Oh... Anyway is a simple google search... Thanks for the tip Magnus... could you upvote me ? I got banned for this nonsense donwvotes...